# Assign a value of 1 when another variable was equal 1 at the last time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data frame:

```
ID      Date  X1  X2  Y
 A  16-07-19  58  50  0
 A  17-07-19  61  83  1
 A  18-07-19  97  38  0
 A  19-07-19  29  77  0
 A  20-07-19  66  71  1
 A  21-07-19  28  74  0
 B  19-07-19  54  65  1
 B  20-07-19  55  32  1
 B  21-07-19  50  30  0
 B  22-07-19  51  38  0
 B  23-07-19  81  61  0
 C  24-07-19  55  29  0
 C  25-07-19  97  69  1
 C  26-07-19  92  44  1
 C  27-07-19  55  97  0
 C  28-07-19  13  48  1
 D  29-07-19  77  27  1
 D  30-07-19  68  50  1
 D  31-07-19  71  32  1
 D  01-08-19  89  57  1
 D  02-08-19  46  70  0
 D  03-08-19  14  68  1
 D  04-08-19  12  87  1
 D  05-08-19  56  13  0
 E  06-08-19  47  35  1
```

I want to create a variable that equals `1` when `Y` was equal `1` at the last time **(for each ID)**, and `0` otherwise.

Also, to exclude all the rows that come after the last time `Y` was equal `1`.

Expected result:

```
ID      Date  X1  X2  Y  Last
 A  16-07-19  58  50  0     0
 A  17-07-19  61  83  1     0
 A  18-07-19  97  38  0     0
 A  19-07-19  29  77  0     0
 A  20-07-19  66  71  1     1
 B  19-07-19  54  65  1     0
 B  20-07-19  55  32  1     1
 C  24-07-19  55  29  0     0
 C  25-07-19  97  69  1     0
 C  26-07-19  92  44  1     0
 C  27-07-19  55  97  0     0
 C  28-07-19  13  48  1     1
 D  29-07-19  77  27  1     0
 D  30-07-19  68  50  1     0
 D  31-07-19  71  32  1     0
 D  01-08-19  89  57  1     0
 D  02-08-19  46  70  0     0
 D  03-08-19  14  68  1     0
 D  04-08-19  12  87  1     1
 E  06-08-19  47  35  1     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove all rows after last `1` in `Y` with compare `Y` with swap order and [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), then get all rows not equal by `0` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last use 
[`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for new column:

```
df = df[df['Y'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().ne(0).sort_index()]
df['Last'] = np.where(df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last'), 0, 1)
print (df)
   ID      Date  X1  X2  Y  Last
0   A  16-07-19  58  50  0     0
1   A  17-07-19  61  83  1     0
2   A  18-07-19  97  38  0     0
3   A  19-07-19  29  77  0     0
4   A  20-07-19  66  71  1     1
6   B  19-07-19  54  65  1     0
7   B  20-07-19  55  32  1     1
11  C  24-07-19  55  29  0     0
12  C  25-07-19  97  69  1     0
13  C  26-07-19  92  44  1     0
14  C  27-07-19  55  97  0     0
15  C  28-07-19  13  48  1     1
16  D  29-07-19  77  27  1     0
17  D  30-07-19  68  50  1     0
18  D  31-07-19  71  32  1     0
19  D  01-08-19  89  57  1     0
20  D  02-08-19  46  70  0     0
21  D  03-08-19  14  68  1     0
22  D  04-08-19  12  87  1     1
24  E  06-08-19  47  35  1     1
```

EDIT:

```
m = df['Y'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().ne(0).sort_index()
df['Last'] = np.where(m.ne(m.groupby(df['ID']).shift(-1)) & m,1,0)
print (df)
   ID      Date  X1  X2  Y  Last
0   A  16-07-19  58  50  0     0
1   A  17-07-19  61  83  1     0
2   A  18-07-19  97  38  0     0
3   A  19-07-19  29  77  0     0
4   A  20-07-19  66  71  1     1
5   A  21-07-19  28  74  0     0
6   B  19-07-19  54  65  1     0
7   B  20-07-19  55  32  1     1
8   B  21-07-19  50  30  0     0
9   B  22-07-19  51  38  0     0
10  B  23-07-19  81  61  0     0
11  C  24-07-19  55  29  0     0
12  C  25-07-19  97  69  1     0
13  C  26-07-19  92  44  1     0
14  C  27-07-19  55  97  0     0
15  C  28-07-19  13  48  1     1
16  D  29-07-19  77  27  1     0
17  D  30-07-19  68  50  1     0
18  D  31-07-19  71  32  1     0
19  D  01-08-19  89  57  1     0
20  D  02-08-19  46  70  0     0
21  D  03-08-19  14  68  1     0
22  D  04-08-19  12  87  1     1
23  D  05-08-19  56  13  0     0
24  E  06-08-19  47  35  1     1
```

Comment: You didn't refer to `Y`. Take a look at the expected result.

Comment: Thank you. Another question: what is the solution to create the `Last` variable, but remain with the rows that come after the last time `Y` equals `1`?